# Book about 2 kids with telekinetic powers. Probably from the 80s or earlier

Tags: story-identification, books

I don't remember much about it. I think the girl accidentally killed her mother (or a friend) who slept in her room for one night while on her period. Her blood was drained out of her.

I think the power had something to do with metals and the blood iron was what caused the power glitch. Both kids got taken to some government facility to be studied/trained.

I can't remember how the girl died but the boy got corrupted by his power and the people in charge.  It had a dark ending.